# Dirichlet series generating function of Euler totient function

Tags: totient-function, dirichlet-series

This is a problem from Wilf's Generatingfunctionology, chapter 2. The exercise is to find the Dirichlet series generating function for the totient function $\varphi(n)$, using the facts
$$\varphi(p^a) = p^a - p^{a-1}$$ 
for prime $p$ and
$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{f(n)}{n^{-s}} = \prod_p \left(1+\frac{f(p)}{p^s} + \frac{f(p^2)}{p^{2s}}+\dots\right)$$
for multiplicative $f$. The solution is $\zeta(s-1)/\zeta(s)$, which I can confirm by multiplying out the terms
$$
\left(1+\frac{p-1}{p^s} + \frac{p^2-p}{p^{2s}}+\dots\right)\left(1+\frac1{p^s}+\frac1{p^{2s}}+\dots\right) = \left(1+\frac1{p^{s-1}}+\frac1{p^{2(s-1)}}+\dots\right).
$$
However, I'm unable to see how to go the forwards direction and recognize the identity
$$
1+\frac{p-1}{p^s} + \frac{p^2-p}{p^{2s}}+\dots = \frac{1+\frac1{p^{s-1}}+\frac1{p^{2(s-1)}}+\dots}{1+\frac1{p^s}+\frac1{p^{2s}}+\dots}.
$$
Could someone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: $$1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \varphi(p^k)p^{-sk} = 1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (p^k-p^{k-1})p^{-sk}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{(1-s)k}-p^{-s}\sum_{k=0}^\infty p^{(1-s)k}= \frac{1-p^{-s}}{1-p^{1-s}}$$

Comment: Crystal clear, thank you very much!

Comment: For a different approach, you could read about [Dirichlet convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution) and their relationship with [φ(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function); there's a very pretty proof to be found among exerpts of those two pages.